# Pygame unable to open file

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am making a simple game, but when I tried to use sound (wav file) I got an error saying that pygame was unable to open file. I will pocy paste my whole code so you can see if I did anything wrong. I feel like I have tried everything, but can't find anything that works. I have seen that other people have had the same problem, but none of that could help me

```
# Shmup game
# Frozen Jam by tgfcoder <https://twitter.com/tgfcoder> licensed under CC-BY-3
# Art from Kenney.nl
import pygame
import random
from os import path

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

#define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED =  (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)


#initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "img")
snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "snd")


font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')
def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        #pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT -10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -7
        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 7
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)
        shoot_sound.play

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_orig = random.choice(meteor_images)
        self.image_orig.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_orig.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = int(self.rect.width * .85 / 2)
       # pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-150, -100)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = random.randrange(-8, 8)
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > 50:
            self.last_update = now
            self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed) % 360
            new_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image_orig, self.rot)
            old_center = self.rect.center
            self.image = new_image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = old_center

    def update(self):
        self.rotate()
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -13

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        # kill it if it moves off the top of the screen
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill

# Load all graphics
background = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "shmupBG.png")).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
player_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "playerShip2_red.png")).convert()
bullet_img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "laserBlue01.png")).convert()
meteor_images = []
meteor_list = ['meteorBrown_big1.png', 'meteorBrown_big2.png', 'meteorBrown_med1.png',
               'meteorBrown_med3.png','meteorBrown_small1.png', 'meteorBrown_small2.png',
               'meteorBrown_tiny1.png']
for img in meteor_list:
    meteor_images.append(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, img)).convert())
# Load all game sounds
shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, "pew.wav"))

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)
score = 0

#Game loop
running = True
while running:
    #keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    #process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing the window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()


    #Update
    all_sprites.update()
    # Check to see if bullet hit a mob
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in hits:
        score += 50 - hit.radius
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)
    # Check to see if a mob hit the player
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    if hits:
        running = False

    #Draw / render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_text(screen, str(score), 18, WIDTH / 2, 10)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

But this is the error message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Steinar Hillestad\Desktop\Spyder\shmup.py", line 137, in <module>
shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(snd_dir, "pew.wav"))
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'C:\\Users\\Steinar Hillestad\\Desktop\\Spyder\\snd\\pew.wav'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was able to fix it! I just changed the soundfile from .wav to .ogg

Answer (score 0):

From my research and from my experience i have a few suggestions.
first of all I would initialize all of pygames modules:

```
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) #frequency, size, channels, buffersize
pygame.init() #turn all of pygame on.
```

Then I would check your pygame version

```
import pygame
print pygame.version.ver
```

that should work

Something you should know is that some versions of pygame does not support 32-bit float Wavs.

Lastly I would check what directory that pygame is looking for your wav  file in.

Other than that I do not have any ideas on how to help you. Maybe someone else has the answer that I cannot give.

Good Luck!